# gatsby-plugin-sitemap Putting trailing slash to homepage only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, sitemap, gatsby-plugin

Hello Guys I am using plugin above to create a sitemap for Gatsby website, and removing forward slashes from all urls, but when I check the sitemap it is putting trailing slash to the homepage only here is the code.

```
serialize: ({ path }) => {
      let domain = process.env.url || 'https://example.com';
      domain =
        domain.charAt(domain.length - 1) === '/' ? domain.slice(1) : domain;
      let pathStr =
        path.charAt(path.length - 1) === '/' ? path.slice(0, -1) : path;
      let url = domain + pathStr;
      console.log(url);
      return {
        url,
        changefreq: 'daily',
        priority: 0.7
      };
    }
```

url is getting displayed in console, and there is no any trailing slashes, but in sitemap there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [v4.7 of Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/v4.7/#trailingslash-option), there's a built-in option to customize the behavior of the trailing slashes across your application. It's currently in beta but should fix your issue.

> **`trailingSlash` Option**
> Currently in Public Beta
>
> Through the [RFC Integrated handling of trailing slashes in Gatsby](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/34205)
> we’ve worked on making the trailing slashes feature a first-class
> citizen in Gatsby. We’re happy to announce that gatsby-config now
> supports a `trailingSlash` configuration with these three main options:
>
> - always: Always add trailing slashes to each URL, e.g. /x to /x/.
> - never: Remove all trailing slashes on each URL, e.g. /x/ to /x.
> - ignore: Don’t automatically modify the URL.

You can simply customize it using:

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: "never"
}
```